# How can I change an attribute using @property in python?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to learn about getters and setters using python. I understand the basic idea but I can't get it to work using the property decorator,

```
class f(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.de = ['d', 'd']
    @property
    def d(self):
        return self.de
    @d.setter
    def d(self, value):
        self.d = value

f = f()
f.d(1)
```

When I run this I get a type error; 'list object is not callable'

Comment: `d` in the `@setter` and `de` in the constructor? Also note that your `de` is a list, so you'd want to add the `value` to the list and not overwrite the entire list, or rename the argument to make it clear that it's a new list which replaces the existing one.

Comment: `f.d[1]` will work

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using a `property` is that it is identical syntactically to regular attribute access.  So:

```
f = f()
f.d = 1
```

(However, I think you want to be setting `self.de = value` in your setter.)

Comment: yes that's how I did it the first time but I'm getting errors from ipython.

Comment: Without `self.de = value` in the setter you will get maximum recursion depth exceeded. The internal `self.d = value` will expand to a call to the setter, which will expand to a call to the setter, and so on.  The error you were getting before was somewhere else, such as the `f.d(1)` error in your example, with `f.d` returning a list?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use a property with a setter. A few thinks to notice:

- Properties are like attributes, get them by using `object.property`. They are not methods, so you do not call them.
- You set properties just like attributes. When a property gets set, the setter function is called. In this case, `someLength.inFeet = 2.5`
- You should not try to set the property *inside* the setter function, ie using `self.inFeet = ...` inside the `inFeet` setter. This will create an infinite (recursive) loop of setter calls.

The exmaple:

```
class Length(object):
    def __init__(self, inInches):
        self.inInches = inInches

    @property
    def inFeet(self):
        return self.inInches / 12.

    @inFeet.setter
    def inFeet(self, valueInFeet):
        self.inInches = valueInFeet * 12.

someLength = Length(12.)
print someLength.inInches
# 12.0
print someLength.inFeet
# 1.0
someLength.inFeet = 2.5
print someLength.inInches
# 30.0
```